# How to add default folders to Every registered User when registered in WordPress site?

Tags: users, user-roles, user-registration, user-access

I need some guidance on my work. As soon as the clients register on a WordPress site. I want the clients to see 4 folders by default: 2002 2003 2004 and Firm Documents.

Once the clients activate their accounts and log into their accounts they must see 4 folders automatically created by default. Then clients upload the files in the respective folders. Once clients upload the files admin will receive them with a notification. Admin must have the ability to download and see the files uploaded. File formats used are Word doc and PDF.

These folders need to be created automatically based on year.

Any idea ??

Thank you

Comment: software recommendations are offtopic here, try the software recommendations stack. Ignoring that though this is a very broad and big question, it sounds like you actually want a file manager or members area with a shared drive, you should ask for that rather than folders as it isn't as clear, but you also need to be much more specific in your question. I can easily see that asking how to do this would be 10 or 20 individual separate questions to ask here, not 1